# Removing numbers from string

Tags: python, string

How can I remove digits from a string?

Comment: With `re`: `result = re.sub(r'[0-9]+', '', s)`

Comment: with regex you will need to add \. also, as it can be decimal number i think. like result = re.sub(r'[0-9\.]+', '', s)

Comment: `"\d"` is the same in a regex as `"[0-9]"`, so you can do `result = re.sub(r"\d+", "", s)` instead. Speed will probably depend on the particular string being used, but for me, `re.sub` took about twice as long as `str.translate` (slightly longer if you don't use a pre-compiled pattern).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, you answer is working fine but it is adding a new line in the file. Any reason?

Comment: @LakshmiYadav `re.sub(r'[0-9]+', '', s)` **removes** found matches (see the second argument that is an empty string), it can't add anything. Check your code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I have 4 line of numeric and alphanumeric strings in a file, I am using for loop and adding your line of code. 

`import fileinput 
import re 

for line in fileinput.input("/Users/xyz/Desktop/temp/i_tmp.txt", inplace=True): 
    print re.sub(r'\b[0-9\.]+','', line)` 

Once I run above code, numbers are vanished but after every line new line is been added.

Comment: @LakshmiYadav It has nothing to do with my regex. Check your `print`.

Comment: This should instead be a duplicate of the much better-asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754587.

Answer (score 279, accepted):

Would this work for your situation?

```
>>> s = '12abcd405'
>>> result = ''.join([i for i in s if not i.isdigit()])
>>> result
'abcd'
```

This makes use of a list comprehension, and what is happening here is similar to this structure:

```
no_digits = []
# Iterate through the string, adding non-numbers to the no_digits list
for i in s:
    if not i.isdigit():
        no_digits.append(i)

# Now join all elements of the list with '', 
# which puts all of the characters together.
result = ''.join(no_digits)
```

As @AshwiniChaudhary and @KirkStrauser point out, you actually do not need to use the brackets in the one-liner, making the piece inside the parentheses a generator expression (more efficient than a list comprehension). Even if this doesn't fit the requirements for your assignment, it is something you should read about eventually :) :

```
>>> s = '12abcd405'
>>> result = ''.join(i for i in s if not i.isdigit())
>>> result
'abcd'
```

Comment: @SeanJohnson Awesome! I'm sure I learned that from somebody else on this site, so the cycle is complete :)

Comment: @RocketDonkey no need of `[]`

Comment: In Python 2.7 and above, you don't need the brackets around the list comprehension. You can leave them out and it becomes a generator expression.

Comment: @RocketDonkey add some explanation too, just seeing the code won't help the OP I guess.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Good point - added (put the list comprehension version first to make the for-loop comparison a bit easier to decipher).

Comment: Jon Clements answer below using `s.translate` is about 10 times faster than the list comprehension (tested with Python 2.7). Just a heads up to anyone reading this later.

Answer (score 125):

And, just to throw it in the mix, is the oft-forgotten `str.translate` which will work a lot faster than looping/regular expressions:

For Python 2:

```
from string import digits

s = 'abc123def456ghi789zero0'
res = s.translate(None, digits)
# 'abcdefghizero'
```

For Python 3:

```
from string import digits

s = 'abc123def456ghi789zero0'
remove_digits = str.maketrans('', '', digits)
res = s.translate(remove_digits)
# 'abcdefghizero'
```

Comment: This approach won't work in Python3. Do instead:

`'abc123def456ghi789zero0'.translate({ord(k): None for k in digits})`

Comment: Best solution for Python2.

Comment: Doesn't work for unicode character strings

Answer (score 24):

Not sure if your teacher allows you to use filters but...

```
"".join(filter(lambda x: x.isalpha(), "a1a2a3s3d4f5fg6h"))
```

returns-

```
'aaasdffgh'
```

Much more efficient than looping...

**Example:**

```
for i in range(10):
  a.replace(str(i),'')
```

Comment: it returns this instead : <filter object at 0x03475FD0>

Comment: You can get a sting back by using `"".join(filter(lambda x: x.isalpha(), "a1a2a3s3d4f5fg6h"))`. That's an empty string in the beginning.

Comment: Or better: "".join(filter(lambda ch: not ch.isdigit(), "a1a2a3s3d4f5fg6h"))  --- so not isdigit is better suits the question. (I can't edit the answer :-( There are too many "edit is awaiting approval" message in the last half year.)

Answer (score 7):

Just a few (others have suggested some of these)

Method 1:

```
''.join(i for i in myStr if not i.isdigit())
```

Method 2:

```
def removeDigits(s):
    answer = []
    for char in s:
        if not char.isdigit():
            answer.append(char)
    return ''.join(answer)
```

Method 3:

```
''.join(filter(lambda x: not x.isdigit(), mystr))
```

Method 4:

```
nums = set(map(int, range(10)))
''.join(i for i in mystr if i not in nums)
```

Method 5:

```
''.join(i for i in mystr if ord(i) not in range(48, 58))
```

Comment: It would be worthwhile to show efficiency comparison on these.

Comment: In method 2, it should be `''.join(answer)` not `''.join(char)`.

Comment: @Sreram: you're absolutely right! Thanks for the bugreport

Answer (score 6):

What about this:

```
out_string = filter(lambda c: not c.isdigit(), in_string)
```

Comment: Output is `<filter object at 0x7f749e1745c0>`. Python3.6

Comment: @TitanFighter You can coerce the generator into a list object by wrapping that returned object from filter into list(filter(...))

Answer (score 4):

Say st is your unformatted string, then run

```
st_nodigits=''.join(i for i in st if i.isalpha())
```

as mentioned above.
But my guess that you need something very simple 
so say **s** is your string
and **st_res** is a string without digits, then here is your code

```
l = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
st_res=""
for ch in s:
 if ch not in l:
  st_res+=ch
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd love to use regex to accomplish this, but since you can only use lists, loops, functions, etc..

here's what I came up with:

```
stringWithNumbers="I have 10 bananas for my 5 monkeys!"
stringWithoutNumbers=''.join(c if c not in map(str,range(0,10)) else "" for c in stringWithNumbers)
print(stringWithoutNumbers) #I have  bananas for my  monkeys!
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question right, one way to do is break down the string in chars and then check each char in that string using a loop whether it's a string or a number and then if string save it in a variable and then once the loop is finished, display that to the user

Comment: A for-loop automatically iterates through every character of a string, so no need of breaking the string into chars.