# How to replace a certain digit number within a string in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, replace

I'm trying to use str.replace to replace the 5 digit numbers in my string and the following does not work:

print((str.replace(\d\d\d\d\d, "n"))

Comment: that is missing, among other errors, a closing `)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing digits with str.replace()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19084443/replacing-digits-with-str-replace)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. Your code has at least two syntax errors, but you can [edit] to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.replace` doesn't support regular expressions. For that use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub).

```
import re
s = 'I have 12345 cows'
print(re.sub(r'\d{5}', "n", s))  # -> I have n cows
```

Breakdown

- `r'...'` - Raw string: backslashes are taken literally
- `\d{5}` - Equivalent to `\d\d\d\d\d`. Braces multiply.