# Strip Numbers From String in Python

Tags: python, nltk

Is there an efficient way to strip out numbers from a string in python?  Using nltk or base python?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want to do?

Comment: if I have a string let's say for example:
x = "I have 3 dogs"
I'd want a way to turn x into:
"I have dogs"

Comment: What would `I have 3x as many dogs as 2 cats` be?

Comment: Or.... "It's the 1st road on your left, then take the 2nd road on the right, then the company you're after is called TRG1 it's about 100m up the road - if you're lazy - you can catch a bus for £2.50" ?

Comment: Check out other good answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851791/removing-numbers-from-string

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, you can use a regular expression for this:

```
import re
output = re.sub(r'\d+', '', '123hello 456world')
print output  # 'hello world'
```

Comment: This is perfect!  Thanks Martin

Comment: Can't go wrong with the regex solution, since it also translate very well to other instances (say he wants to remove letters next).

Comment: The best answer. Works like charm

Answer (score 15):

[`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) should be efficient.

```
In [7]: 'hello467'.translate(None, '0123456789')
Out[7]: 'hello'
```

To compare `str.translate` against `re.sub`:

```
In [13]: %%timeit r=re.compile(r'\d')
output = r.sub('', my_str)
   ....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.46 µs per loop

In [16]: %%timeit pass
output = my_str.translate(None, '0123456789')
   ....: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 713 ns per loop
```

Comment: The problem is: `str.translate` is a bit difficult to make both 2.x/3.x compatible :(

Comment: So you'd need `my_str.translate({ord(ch): None for ch in '0123456789'})` in 3.x

Comment: I wonder how long r.sub() takes? Say, under conditions where you want to do this over multiple strings and you've pre-compiled the regex.

Comment: @Ross - Judging from the code I put in my answer, 5.46µs.

Comment: @Rob - Ah right, I missed that the first line is the set up line. Looking at some best/worst cases translate seems to perform much better at worst case scenarios. Using 'python -m timeit' I came across the following in favour of translate;
`'123hello 456world' - x5.0`
`'1234567890987654321012345678909876543210' - x17.0`
`'5a$%&^@)9lhk45g08j%Gmj3g09jSDGjg0034k' - x9.0`
`'hello world im your boss' - x 1.8`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method using `str.join()`, `str.isnumeric()`, and a generator expression which will work in 3.x:

```
>>> my_str = '123Hello, World!4567'
>>> output = ''.join(c for c in my_str if not c.isnumeric())
>>> print(output)
Hello, World!
>>>
```

This will also work in 2.x, if you use a unicode string:

```
>>> my_str = u'123Hello, World!4567'
>>> output = ''.join(c for c in my_str if not c.isnumeric())
>>> print(output)
Hello, World!
>>>
```

Hmm.  Throw in a paperclip and we'd have an episode of *MacGyver*.

## Update

I know that this has been closed out as a duplicate, but here's a method that works for both Python 2 and Python 3:

```
>>> my_str = '123Hello, World!4567'
>>> output = ''.join(map(lambda c: '' if c in '0123456789' else c, my_str))
>>> print(output)
Hello, World!
>>>
```