# Python lists and web scraping

Tags: python, string, list, web-scraping

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
```

opening Nytimes and reading the page

```
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.nytimes.com').read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(response)

data = []
```

I am taking all the headings on the homepage and taking them in to a list

```
for story_heading in soup.find_all(class_="story-heading"):
        story_title = story_heading.text.replace("\n", "").strip()
        new_story_title = story_title.encode('utf-8')
```

im converting the words of each title into a list

```
        words = new_story_title.split()
        data.append(words)
        print data
```

Now, I want to remove the numbers in this text how can i do it?

Comment: That may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851791/removing-numbers-from-string

Comment: Could you add some examples as well? What is this text and which numbers do you want to remove?

Comment: Be carefule, there have been real numbers in the original text, as well as the numbers coming from unicode encoding. Which ones do you want to remove?

Comment: I just want to append "alphabetical elements" into the list @tfv

Comment: These are few titles guys!! 
I need to take out the numbers below including "$2" if i can 
""[De Blasio to Propose $2 Billion for New York City’s Hospital System]
[Trump Agrees to Interview With Megyn Kelly, Fox News Says 7:32 PM] 
[8 Years of Lessons Temper Obama’s Foreign Policy Goals]
[Goodell Remains Firmly in Control 9:00 PM ET]
[Students’ National Anthem Is Stopped at 9/11 Memorial 9:22 PM ET]""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
clean_text = ''.join([i for i in data if not i.isdigit()])
```

Source: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851791/removing-numbers-from-string)

```
words = ''.join([i for i in new_story_title if not i.isdigit()]).split()
data.append(words)
print data
```

Try the code above

Comment: I Tried it buddy 

It says: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'isdigit'

Comment: is there any way i can append everything into single list rather than nested list? @tfv

Comment: @Nguyễn Việt Hưng IT Worked.

Instead of list your code just processed the normal text. Thank you for the idea.

Comment: @KishanJangam you're wellcome

Answer (score 0):

**[EDIT]** Updated for taking out digits in words:

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

#opening Nytimes and reading the page

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.nytimes.com').read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(response)

data = []

#I am taking all the headings on the homepage and taking them in to a list

for story_heading in soup.find_all(class_="story-heading"):
    story_title = story_heading.text.replace("\n", "").strip()
    new_story_title = story_title.encode('utf-8')

#im converting the words of each title into a list

    words = new_story_title.split()
    data.append(words)
print data

clean_data=[]
for i in data:
    for j in i:
        word=[]
        for k in j:
            if not k.isdigit():
                word.append(k)
        clean_data.append(''.join(word))
print clean_data
```