# Remove everything after a number in a string

Tags: python

Is this possible? To delete everything in a string after any number?

Eg.:

```
some_text = "123 Text"
some_text_2 = "456 Foo"
```

I want to get only `123` and `456` without the space, and those numbers would be a random number

Comment: I don't want to get the space, but I know to remove spaces with `replace` function

Comment: To simplify, is it reasonable to use `some_text.split()[0]`?

Comment: I'm confused, do you want to delete everything after a number or keep everything after a number?

Comment: I want to delete everything after the number @juanpa.arrivillaga. Sorry, I wrote badly the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With little search on Stack Overflow.

[Removing numbers from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851791/removing-numbers-from-string)

For Python 2:

```
from string import digits

s = 'abc123def456ghi789zero0'
res = s.translate(None, digits)
# 'abcdefghizero'
```

For Python 3:

```
from string import digits

s = 'abc123def456ghi789zero0'
remove_digits = str.maketrans('', '', digits)
res = s.translate(remove_digits)
# 'abcdefghizero'
```

And add a `replace` function to remove the space.

Comment: It is really not a good thing to copy an answer directly without improving it. Better to mark as duplicate.

Comment: He wants to keep the number, not remove the number.

Comment: @Barmar in the previous edit of his post : `I want to get only Text and Foo`