# Removing all numeric characters in a string, python

Tags: python, extract

Im looking to remove every single number in a string. More specifically, i'm looking to remove all numbers in the following codes string

Comp_String = "xxf1,aff242342"

how can one do this. (Obviously inside the code). I have found many answers to questions about removing the actual parts of the code that are letters but not numbers. Please explain aswell what your code is actually doing

Comment: `print ''.join([i for i in Comp_String if not i.isdigit()])`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the answer here 
[Removing numbers from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851791/removing-numbers-from-string)

From this answer:

```
comp_string = "xxf1,aff242342"
new_string = ''.join([i for i in comp_string if not i.isdigit()])
```

It creates a new string using .join from a list. That list is created using a list comprehension that iterates through characters in your original string, and excludes all digits.

Answer (score 2):

This will remove any characters that ARE NOT letters, by going through each character and only adding it to the output if it is a letter:

```
output_string = ""

for char in Comp_String:
    if char.isalpha():
        output_string = output_string + char
```

This will remove any characters that ARE numbers, by going through each character and only adding it to the output if it is not a number:

```
output_string = ""

for char in Comp_String:
    if not char.isdigit():
        output_string = output_string + char
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with regular expressions using the https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html module. The only regex you need is **\d**, which notates digits.

```
from re import sub

comp_string = "xxf1,aff242342"
print(sub(pattern=r"\d", repl=r"", string=comp_string))
```