# removing substring

Tags: python, regex, replace

Can someone please hint my mistake. Im trying to remove numbers from the string. Findall succefully finds the number but replace does not replace them with empty string. here is the code:

```
import re
x = 'John2345 can5 code with python3'
extra = re.findall('\d{1,9}', x)
x.replace(extra, '')
x
```

and here is the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-334-bfc161d88f65> in <module>()
      2 x = 'ererf ergg5 erg 545 eeg'
      3 extra = re.findall('\d{1,9}', x)
----> 4 x.replace(extra, '')
      5 x

TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

Cheers,
Sia

Comment: Why not use `re.sub`.

Comment: See [Removing numbers from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851791/removing-numbers-from-string).

Comment: Thanks mate, it worked with re.sub.

Comment: Please select any of the answers below as answered  or upvote if it helped, instead of thanking each and every one.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`re.sub()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
re.sub(r'\d+' ,'', x)
```

Answer (score 0):

x is a string, extra is a list, right? The best hint is in the error message you recieved:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

What python actually tells you, in human language is "I can't get your list object as argument here!! give me a string!!!"

Comment: Thanks mate, understood. Cheers.