# I need to split up a string so it prints out just the name

Tags: python

I have a string (down below) and I am asked to write code so it only prints out the name

```
s = "jimmy.clancy5@mail.ucd.ie"

output =" Jimmy Clancy"
```

my code below splits the string into tokens
the first name is correct but for the second it also prints `5@mail`
I'm not exactly sure how to remove it

```
    import sys
    input = sys.stdin.readlines()

    for name in input:
        name = name.strip().split(".")
        second_name = name[1]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing numbers from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851791/removing-numbers-from-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that `complete name` is present before `@` and `first name`, `last name` is separated by `.` than following code will work for you

```
   s = "jimmy.clancy5@mail.ucd.ie"
    name = s.split("@")[0]
    fname , lastname = name.split(".")
```

Comment: i removed the digit and used your code and it worked , thanks!